# recover message discarded in GCM

Tags: android

i want to  ask about GCM. in document of google [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#collapsible)

note that 100 message stored without discard in case application is offline and i have much than 100 message from server sent to GCM my application  should respond by syncing with the server to recover the discarded messages.so how to sync i should? thank you so much

Comment: have you thought about storing the messages in a DB and then pushing them to GCM , and then store the responses from GCM there

Comment: i want to storing message in DB of client and i want to receive message which my server sent to GCM.i want synchronize.i am doing my application about synchronize and app offline